# Tensorflow Estimator error: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am training a TF Boosted Trees estimator, which is giving me an error:

```
incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

On CloudML I get:

```
Command '['python', '-m', u'trainer.model', u'--job-type', u'remote', '--job-dir', u'gs://xxx']' died with signal 7.
```

after an ~1 hour of training. I am training on the CPU. This suggests that there is a Memory leak, but I'm only using TF code, so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
def build_training_input_fn():

    def parse_record(record):

        transformed_feature_spec = transformed_metadata.schema.as_feature_spec()

        transformed_features = tf.parse_single_example(record, transformed_feature_spec)
        cols_to_remove = []
        transformed_labels = transformed_features.pop(LABEL_KEY)
        transformed_features = {key: value for (key, value) in transformed_features.items() if
                            key not in cols_to_remove}
        return transformed_features, transformed_labels

    def input_fn(file_pattern):
        files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern=file_pattern) 
        files.apply(
        tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(
            lambda filename: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename),
            cycle_length=32,
            block_length=1,
            sloppy=True,
        ))
        dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.map_and_batch(
        map_func=parse_record, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=False,
        num_parallel_batches=1))

        return dataset

return input_fn

classifier = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier()
input_fn_train = build_training_input_fn()
classifier.train(input_fn=input_fn_train)
```

where I am reading TF records created by Apache Beam.

I'm not sure how it's possible to get such errors, I know the data in TF records is good, and I can train XGB/Catboost using the same set.

Can anyone help?